# SSIS 0x80040e37 oracle dataflow saying that a table doesnt exist in 2016 (but works fine in 2017)

Tags: oracle, ssis, business-intelligence, data-integration

I have a table comprised of columns varchar2's of ascending length. They range from varchar2(1911) to varchar2 (2865).

I use an Oledb Connection to the database and in the Dataflow source editor, under the 'table or view' I am able to see the table. However when I select that table I get the following error:

Error Code: 0x80040e37 
Error at DataflowTask[Ole DB Source[1]]: Opening a rowset for "inserttablename" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

I do not think it is a datatype length issue as it is able to find a table with a range of varchar2(3993) to varchar2(4000). Maybe it is the cumulative size of the table?

Whats more strange is that it works fine when targeting SQL Server 2017, it is only in 2016 and 2014 that it does not appear to work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

It also works with AdoNet connections as well as ODBC connections.

Comment: Have you retargeted your package to run on SSIS 2014/16? You may want to recreate the DB connection.

Comment: I had retargeted, yes, but redefining the connection does nothing. Even starting a brand new package from scratch gives me the same issue

Comment: Have you run a SQL Server Profiler on a working and non working destination?  This may give you a clue.  Also you should check the server parameters to ensure things like the collation match between 2017 and 2016/2014 versions, etc.

Comment: More than likely your driver is the cause of failure here. Have you tried using the Attuinity oracle driver for SSIS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017